# How can I embed a copy of a table's column as a table within a new column of the original table?

Tags: powerquery, m

If I have a table like this:

[image]

How can I add an embedded copy of *Column2* in place of the Error in *Custom*? I would want the exact same embedded copy of *Column2* in each row of *Custom*.

I tried using `Table.FromColumns({{[Column2]}})`
and `Table.FromList({[Column2]})` , but they both only embed a one row table with only the current row's value from *Column2*.

I want the embedded table on each row of *Custom* to have all of *Column2*'s values, like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `each` statement `[Column2]` is a shorter version of `_[Column2]`, where `_` is the current row. You need to include the step name if you want the whole column. For example, if the current step is `Table`, you can use `Table.FromColumns({Table[Column2]})` in the each statement to add a one-column table consisting of Column2's values. Note that in this case `Table[Column2]` returns a list so we only need one pair of curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "Column2", "Custom")
in
    #"Duplicated Column"
```

maybe you should simply duplicate the column ?